# TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, apache, pdo

I'm having some trouble with a PHP Script, using WordPress on Apache with PHP 5.x.

I've built a WP plugin that is doing some query on a SQLServer, using PDO, but, on a query, the WP debug is returning this warning:

```
[22-Jan-2018 13:40:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  (null) in C:\xampp\htdocs\confart_intranet\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\myplugin.php on line 342
[22-Jan-2018 13:40:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 258 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].  in C:\xampp\htdocs\confart_intranet\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\myplugin.php on line 342
```

If I run the query on SSMS, I get always a result, but in PHP I got an empty array.

Thank you all for your help and your support.

Comment: I think that could be a SQL Server timeout, because on the SQL Server Profiler after the interested query the SPID is changing.

Another interesting thing is that when Apache is doing the query through the SP sp_prepexec, the param **@p1** _is null_

Comment: SQL Server has no timeout at all. All timeouts that you can imagine are CLIENT timeouts

Comment: SQL Server have Remote Query timeout. But is set to '0', so the settings are correct